# Getting the session details via websockets in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've created a project in Node.js, users are able to create a 'room'. Users login via a html form which submits their details as a HTTP request. The server then adds a token to their session '`req.session.auth = true`'. I want to broadcast socket messages to users where their .auth token is true.

**Question:**
how can I access session information outside of a HTTP request? whilst using (if correct):

```
var MemoryStore = require('connect').session.MemoryStore,
    sessionStore = new MemoryStore();
```

e.g.

```
socket.on('message', function(data){
//Access user session here.
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of things to be said here, but they are all explained better in the following post:

http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/